# htaccess redirect if one query param matches

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from `/somedir/index.php?action=something&id=x` to `/index.php?action=something&id=x`

Only if `action` = `something`. `id` is dynamic.

Most recently I've tried this with no luck. What is wrong with this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=something($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=($|&)
RewriteRule ^somedir/index\.php$ /index.php?action?something&id=%2$ [NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

Note: somedir has an index.php and this rule in its htaccess. Will that result in conflicts?

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule instead of your rule in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)action=something($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=x($|&)
RewriteRule ^somedir/index\.php$ /index.php?action=something&id=x [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The result will not conflict.

Comment: I see `id=x` in that rule. Does that mean `id` will always be `x`? It's a dynamic parameter

Comment: X will take value in second condition.

Comment: Are you changing that "somedir" to actual dir name or keeping it the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(action|id)=([^&]+)&(?:.*&)?(action|id)=([^&]+)(?:$|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^somedir/index\.php$ /index.php?%1=%2&%3=%4 [NC,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```